# How to redirect url with port to https with Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect

I'm trying to set up an nginx webserver and have ssl set up.
I can currently access the site with my server url and also through http and have it redirect to https. However I can still access my server with http://server.com:8089. Doing so does not redirect my web page to https nor is the connection secure anymore.

How can I set up my webpage http://server.com:8089 to redirect to https://server.com?

My current nginx conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server.com;
    return 301 https://server.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name server.com;
    keepalive_timeout 70;

    // ssl block //

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8089;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to configure your application server that is listening on port 8089 to do the redirect when it is accessed directly. How to do that depends on what that application server is.

Comment: what you can do is to configure a server block with a listen on the external ip on port 8089, and porxy pass from there the same way. I have never done this, no no guarantees, but this should work if the application listens only on 127.0.0.1...

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

...
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8069;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
...

Ref: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/run-odoo-with-nginx-at-port-80

Comment: This can't be configured in nginx, it can only be configured on the application server.